# Parsing JSON data without property names

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I hope that I have given right title to my question. I have trying to parse some JSON string. I came across JSON.net and found it to be very useful. Below is the format of my JSON string,

```
{  
  "TotalRecords":2,
  "Category":3,
  "pRecords": [  
    [  
      "1",
      "11/11/2015 09:35",
      "Record 1",
      "60"
    ],
    [  
      "2",
      "11/11/2015 10:40",
      "Record 2",
      "48.5"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am unable to format the JSON string correctly here on SO so don't mind as it is just to give the idea and explain problem. I am now stuck because I am not sure how to parse pRecords data as it does not have any names and have just the values. May be this is a very basic question but during my search I am unable to find the solution for this.

Comment: It's an array. If your property `pRecords` is `List<List<string>>` it should parse fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code written in c#

```
public class RootObject
{
     public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
     public int Category { get; set; }
     public string[][] pRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Use json.net to deserialize

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>('your json');
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. My mistake was that I gave names to un-named json data in my property classes and was wondering how to parse data by mapping named property class and un-named json data.